# Asp.net mvc dropdown-list from database with 2 data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do a dropdownlist from database that have 2 values (zipcode and city). In my table I only have "ZipCode" and "City" meaning I don't have id and I've used my ZipCode as id so far.

I want the dropdown show
"Select city"

- New York 10001
- New York 10010
- Los Angeles 90001
- etc

But now it's only showing like this:

- New York
- New York
- Los Angeles

So if there is two New York then you don't know which one to choose since there is no zipcode. I could change that I shows only zipcodes and not cities and that works, but I want to show both.

In my Customers.cs I have this:

```
public partial class Customers
{
 public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Cities Cities { get; set; }
}
```

In my Cities.cs I have this:

```
public partial class Cities
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Cities()
    {
        this.Customer = new HashSet<Customers>();
    }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Customers> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In my create.cshtml I have this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode, "Cities", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ZipCode", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

In controller it's like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
        ViewBag.ZipCode = new SelectList(db.Cities, "ZipCode", "City");
        return View();
}
```

How can I change this? I'm stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ViewBag.ZipCode = db.Cities.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = c.ZipCode,
    Text = $"{c.City} {c.ZipCode}",
});
```

Comment: Ah awesome thanks!! That worked :)